# on touch of image, image view to fullscreen and zoom should work

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, fullscreen, picasso

I'm loading Image from server to imageview. I'm using Picasso to load the image from server to imageview.

On touch of that image, i want it to appear fullscreen and even zoom/tap should work.

I don't know what to do for this, Please help me with suggestions or some examples.

I found few examples, but there was more than 1000 lines code, I couldn't find it helpful and I didn't understand what to do with it.

Thanks.
this is my code.

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setOnClickListener(this);

Picasso.with(this).load("http://Imageurl").into(image);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.image:

            //what to do here ?

             break;  
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some simple steps you should follow.

1. Create one full-screen Activitywith `ImageView` only.
2. You need to implement library for Pinch to Zoom In/Zoom Out Images. Through which you can zoom In/Out your Imageview.
3. By Clicking on Imageview Start that Activity and Finish on `onBackPress()`

There are some of the examples of library you can use.

> https://github.com/martinwithaar/PinchToZoom
>
> https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage

Comment: Thank you, Let me implement this and come back to you. Thanks is advance

Comment: Thank you @Pragnesh , the 2nd link worked for me, i.e., 

https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage

Comment: Glad it helped @Lokesh

Answer (score 3):

You can use following cusome class for implment zooming functionality in your layout which will work for me better.

```
public class TouchOrZoomImageView extends ImageView
{
    Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

    float width, height;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchOrZoomImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchOrZoomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context)
    {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        mMatrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                mMatrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG)
                        {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                            float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                            if (scaleWidth < width)
                            {
                                deltaX = 0;
                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            else if (scaleHeight < height)
                            {
                                deltaY = 0;
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);

                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            mMatrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        if (bm != null)
        {
            bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
            bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
        }
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x)
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(
                    Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale)
            {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            }
            else if (saveScale < minScale)
            {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height
                    - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height)
            {
                mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    mMatrix.getValues(m);
                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                    {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width)
                        {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (x < -right)
                                mMatrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0)
                                mMatrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(),
                        detector.getFocusY());
                mMatrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    if (x < -right)
                        mMatrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0)
                        mMatrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        mMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        mMatrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }
}
```

Now put after this class as view in your layout whereyou want to show like bellow is the example

```
<com.yourpackagename.TouchOrZoomImageView 
    android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
    android:src="@drawable/nature_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Then after you can load data or set src same as you are setting in ImageView, This class inherit ImageView class so you can set all property which is using image use.

Comment: Just put this class as view where you want to zoom it. like I want to zoom in dialog then I put as same image in dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but its not working. In My XML i have replaced ur code and created a class with same name and pasted complete code but the image itself not displaying